# How do I select elements with contentEditable = true in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style elements with contentEditable = "true" (the elements being table cells if that changes anything). I've tried using `td[contenteditable]`, `td[contenteditable=true]`, `td[contenteditable="true"]`, and none of them work. Is there even a selector for these or will I have to use JavaScript?

Here's the HTML:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>content</th>
    <th>editable content</th>
    <th>content</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">I'm editable!</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">I'm editable!</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">I'm editable!</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: show us your html

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/noputicufe/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I would use `[contenteditable="true"], [contenteditable=""]`

Comment: Voting to Close as this issue can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use four spaces in front of a line it will be formatted as text. With your answer do that to the first line to make it a bit nicer.

Using your example HTML code the selector `td[contenteditable="true"]` [should work](https://jsfiddle.net/t8dk8fne/).

If you're using an older browser that could explain why it's not working. Though [this](https://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) would suggest you would have to use something IE6, as CSS 2.1 is pretty widely supported by now.

If you haven't done so check your Browser Debug Console (most modern browsers have it available by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>) and look for any errors related to CSS.

Comment: When a question is not formatted properly you can [suggest an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41678105/edit). And if the code in the question already works, you can flag to close.

Comment: A valid edit needs more than 6 characters changed. By just replacing the apostrophes you would not reach that limit. In addition it's meant as a information for a new user. Thanks for pointing it out anyway. I probably should've given that information as a comment rather than making it part of my answer.